# It already exists OR it is already existing before

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

Let's say a group of *students* is speaking in front of a classroom. In the middle of their talk about a brain research, they just said ''we call this '*paralysis analysis*''. After that, their *teacher reacted* and said:

> "You are the one who coined that phrase, **it already exists** before you even call it that way."

Or

> "You are the one who coined that phrase, **it is already existing** before you even call it that way."

The two sentences above I think is grammatical, but what tense should I use to clearly communicate what I am trying to say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of your sentences is idiomatic.

1. *Call it that way* is not an English construction. We say "called it that" or "gave it that name" or "used that name for it".
2. And in this case it's a little more complicated. You're using the pronoun *it* to refer to two different things: the phenomenon (*call **it** that*) and the name (***it*** existed).
3. The verb *exist* is [**stative**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info) and is not usually cast in the progressive form, except as an adjectival participle: it bears a "progressive" sense inherently.
4. You are casting *exist* in the wrong tense: the teacher is referring not to the **present** existence of the phrase but to its **past** existence, before the students used it.
5. In any case, *exist* is an awkward term for a phrase: what you probably mean is that the phrase was "in use" or "current".

What you want to say is something like:

> You didn't coin that phrase: it was current in the field before you used it.

However, I think the teacher is being a little unfair. Saying "we call this *analysis paralysis*" doesn't necessarily claim that the students invented the term—*we* can mean everybody who studies the phenomenon. The ambiguity can be resolved by using the passive: "*This is called* analysis paralysis".

Comment: Brilliant! Moreover, In my construction can I say this: ''You didn't coin that phrase, the ''paralysis analysis'' term was already in use before you called it that'' --grammatical?

Comment: @JohnArvin Mostly. We'd say *the term 'analysis paralysis' was already in use*. ... By the way, I've just noticed that you say *paralysis analysis*, which my eye automatically read the other way around -- that's the term I've always encountered, meaning "inaction (paralysis) due to over-analysis".